# How to map one entity to two tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

```
public class Company  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(schema = "company",
        name = "company_settings",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"))
    private List<Settings> settings;
}
```

migration on flyway

```
    CREATE TABLE company.company_settings (
                                                id serial primary key,
                                                ...
);
```

Settings class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "company")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Settings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

}
```

problem what i see

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "company.settings" does not exist
```

why i dont want to use table name in @Table - i will need to use Settings class for another table as well. It will be the same table but for user.

```
public class User  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(schema = "user",
        name = "user_settings",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<Settings> settings;
}
```

i want to have 2 table `user_settings` and `company_settings` in different schemas.
is it possible to do with `@JoinTable`?
I can use one class and extend it for user and company, or i can have 1 table for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

The table with which an entity class is associated is a characteristic of the entity class itself, not of other classes that have a relationship with it.  So no, in a given persistence unit, you cannot have one entity class mapped to multiple different tables.

But maybe you can get close to what you want with a mapped superclass of multiple distinct entities.  You could have:

```
// Not an entity, but contains mapping information for entity subclasses
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class Settings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "company", name = "company_settings")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CompanySettings extends Settings {

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "company", name = "user_settings")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserSettings extends Settings {

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

The `Company` and `User` entities would need to map their relationships to their respective varieties of `Settings`, but you could nevertheless reduce code duplication between the settings entities this way. For example,

```
public class Company  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "company")
    private List<CompanySettings> settings;
}
```

And you could handle `CompanySettings`es and `UserSettings`es generically as `Settings`es wherever, if anywhere, it makes sense to do so (which does not include in `Company` or `User`).